# admin_enqueue_scripts not working in specific admin page

Tags: wordpress

This is my code in functions.php file.

```
function my_enqueue($hook) {
if ( 'bookings' != $hook ) {
    return;
}
wp_enqueue_style('datatablecss','//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
wp_enqueue_style('datatablecss2','//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css' );
wp_enqueue_script('datatablejs','//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js',array(),'1.0',false);
wp_enqueue_script('datatablejs2','//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js',array(),'1.0',false);}add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
```

My custom page name is bookings
and url is https://hireo.co.uk/wp-admin/admin.php?page=bookings
Any Solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'options'){ 
    wp_enqueue_style( 'akbank-bootstrap-min-css', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'akbank-bootstrap-theme-css', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'akbank-bootstrap-min-js', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js');
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score -1):

if condition set is_admin()

```
function my_enqueue($hook) {
if ( 'bookings' != $hook ) {
    return;
}
if ( is_admin() ) {
wp_enqueue_style('datatablecss','//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
wp_enqueue_style('datatablecss2','//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css' );
wp_enqueue_script('datatablejs','//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js',array(),'1.0',false);
wp_enqueue_script('datatablejs2','//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js',array(),'1.0',false);}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
}
```

Comment: It didn't answer the question. The OP asked, even if the user is an admin how should he enqueue scripts specifically to certain pages without affecting all pages in the wp admin